# Magento2 duplicates entries in admin configuration after field id changes

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

I changed some Id's in the `adminhtml/system.xml` configuration file & now I got some duplicated entries.

I tried deleting the old values in the **core_config_data** table but the old fields continue showing in the admin.

any ideas ?

Comment: Please clear the cache and make sure data gets saved.

Comment: Thanks Kamlesh of course I cleared magento cache. Also redis cache, var folder public folder, compile all over again, search the key in the damped db with gerp and also search all the magento file system for the id it is really a mystery where this entry live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that it was another module with similar system.xml adding the extra configuration to the same group ID.